# Parallel infinite loop

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm using threads for the first time in Java. Let me know what here is causing an infinite loop and how I can resolve it. I think the issue is being caused by the fact that I'm using a GUI along with threading.

What happens is that infinite copies of the GUI pop up.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
                new RollplayGUI();
        }
    });
}

public RollplayGUI() {
    createGUI();
    RollplayGUI rg = new RollplayGUI();
    Thread trg = new Thread(rg);
    trg.setDaemon(true);
    trg.run();
}

public void run() {
        //Some fun stuff my daemon thread is supposed to do 
    }
```

The reason I'm doing this is that the run() method does some net code that blocks until it gets a connection from another program.

Comment: Have any of the comments below helped? You should provide some feedback as to how it turned out on your end and if you found a solution.

Answer (score 7):

Your code is failing because the RollplayGUI constructor is instantiating a new RollplayGUI object.  This will result in an infinite loop and likely a ...   stack overflow.

Comment: A smile to my face when someone's first SO question is about... an SO.

Answer (score 2):

One reason you get an infinite number of gui's is that you have each RollplayGUI creates a new RollplayGUI right after it is instantiated.

Additionally, you should call start() on Thread object, not run. If you call run then it's as if you're not doing threading. start() handles the threading properly.

Answer (score 0):

This is an infinite loop because you have your RollbackGUI() create a new RollbackGUI(). Remove this line:

```
RollplayGUI rg = new RollplayGUI();
```

Answer (score 0):

What Justin said, but once that is fixed you're never starting your thread. You're just creating a Thread object (which will represent the thread when and if it starts) and then executing its run() method in the original thread. Use trg.start() instead of trg.run() to actually launch the thread.

Answer (score 0):

When you create your first `RollplayGUI`, the constructor is called. Inside that constructor you create a new `RollplayGUI`, whose constructor will again call `RollplayGUI`. This will occur indefinitely, which is the infinite loop.

The line is

```
RollplayGUI rg = new RollplayGUI();
```